# My debian installation has no desktop enviroment, and no internet access

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I watch the youtube https://youtu.be/Y7a9SC_apP4?t=5m9s , in the video there are choices to choose which desktop environment to choose. However, my installation has no such choice, why? I use the iso dvd here: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/multi-arch/iso-dvd/.

[image]

[image]

Something wrong? because after installation, I don't have any graphic interface at all.

#### edit 1

Following the suggestion, after execute `startx`.

- `tty1` becomes a mouse and terminal and some blank space hybrid.
- the mouse can even select text.
- the terminal becomes very small and bounded at the top left corner. It seems that it has recognized my screen's resolution, because the fonts are small and sharp. The white part is the consequence of selecting the text.
- the mouse becomes a 'X' at the blank space, and an 'I' in the terminal region.
- tty2-6 is also terminal but with large fonts, tty7 not able to enter.
  [image]

  **it seems that xorg is functional, how can I check if I have installed desktop manager'lxdm,lightdm' and desktop enviroment 'gnome,kde,lxde'?**

Comment: If you select the checkbox to the left of "Debian desktop environment" you should see the available DEs appear; does that help?

Comment: @StephenKitt not help, it didn't show up

Comment: If you have internet access with that PC you can always install them via `apt-get` after the system is set up.

Comment: @Fiximan The problem is that I don't have internet, because it has a strange wireless card. I have describe my situation here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307215/debian-no-x-no-internet-how-to-compile-the-wireless-driver

Comment: @buzhidao Can you try if there is a startx command to boot to UI.

Comment: @Varad please see my edit, it seems that xorg is functional..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the multi-arch DVD doesn't contain all the packages needed for all the desktops (again) - it's overflowed the capacity of a single DVD. :-(

Better to talk about this kind of thing on the debian-cd list at debian-cd@lists.debian.org

Answer (score 0):

Changed the password, reinstalled `xserver-xorg` by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
```

After a reboot it worked for me. Notice: I removed the `.XAuthority` files in `/home/username` by:

```
sudo rm /home/username/.XAuthority*
```

Ref Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/143179/startx-doesnt-work

Comment: No internet access.

Comment: Beside, I think xorg works fine, I probably has no desktop manager and desktop environment..

Answer (score 0):

Desktop manager is not always needed, look at this post:
[INSTALL LXDE (OR KDE) WITHOUT THE STARTUP MANAGERS](https://debiantalk.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/install-lxde-or-kde-without-the-startup-managers/)

I would try by uninstalling the desktop manager if any:

```
apt-get -y remove lightdm
```

Then try again starting X

Comment: no internet... If you are interested, the primary thing is to solve the driver trouble..http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307215/debian-no-x-no-internet-how-to-compile-the-wireless-driver

Comment: yes, without internet connection to remove an installed package you need to use `dpkg -l | grep lightdm` to find the full name of the Light Desktop Manager and then `dpkg -r FULLNAMEOFPACKAGE` then try with startx again.

Comment: no output, is it possible that multi-arch has no desktop environment ported with them? only a guess.