# Debian, no X, no internet, how to compile the wireless driver?

Tags: debian, package-management, system-installation, debian-installer

I have installed debian, but the wireless card is less common, Debian won't recognize it. The driver need to be compiled and installed, but to do that, I must have `build-essential` and `Linux-header-generic` updated.

[The instruction of how to compile and install the driver](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs/wiki/RTL8723BS-module-building-instruction-for-Debian-GNU-Linux) is written here however assumed a internet connection.

How can I achieve this without Internet and without gui?

I manage an outline here:

1. download all the packages and its dependences and the dependences' dependences needed to build the driver. Basically it is `build-essentials` and the newer version of `linux-image` in the backports and `linux-headers` corresponding to that image. **How to download them from a ubuntu machine or a windows machine?**
2. make sure the above step has downloaded all the dependences, because in this offline computer, I don't want to see any dependences issues, because it can solve it.
3. copy the packages to a usb drive, and read the content of that usb drive. Then install the packages by `dpkg`. **How to read the content and enter the usb folder from terminal?**
4. make and make install the wireless driver from terminal. this step is straightforward if above two are succeed.
5. connect the wifi from terminal, download desktop environment and do the updates. **How to do this, need wifi-menu?**

#### edit 1

The debian installed is the latest [stable version:multi-arch.iso](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/multi-arch/iso-dvd/). The tablet model has a 64bit cpu and 32bit UEFI, 64G storage and 2G ram, the wireless card is `rtl8723bs`.

#### edit 2 output of lspci

[image]

Comment: Please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R No output.

Comment: Run `update-pciids` then `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @GAD3R first command not found, I can't connect via ethernet. It's a tablet with weird wireless card.

Comment: @GAD3R The wireless card is `Realtek RTL8723BS 802.11n SDIO Wireless LAN`, the driver is on github .  I have put the link in the post. Do you know how to check if I have a desktop environment installed?

Answer (score 3):

Update your system and install the required package to compile the wifi driver using [PrintUris](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/PrintUris) tool.

Run the following commands:

```
apt-get --print-uris update > myupdateurilist.htm
apt-get --print-uris --yes install build-essential  > packageuri.htm
apt-get --print-uris --yes install linux-headers-4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64  > packageuri2.htm
```

Copy `myupdateurilist.htm` , `packageuri.htm` and `packageuri2.htm` to your USB stick. Open `htm` file on another connected OS and download them one by one :(e,g: on Linux machine)

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux-compiler-gcc-4.9-x86_4.6.4-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb
```

It's recommanded  to fix broken packages and upgrade your distrubution using `print-uris` tool .

Once downloaded install all packages on your offline machine, Then compile the needed driver.

Comment: I think the three line code snippet is execute on the offline machine. For that machine is just fresh installed, it doesn't know package `build-essential`, when I try to execute `apt-get --print-uris --yes install build-essential  > packageuri.htm` it returns `package build-essential has no installation candidate.`

Comment: Run the update first

Comment: no internet, what is the purpose of update? `failed to fetch` it returns..

Comment: Use `apt-offline` tool https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2014/01/30/how-to-manage-packages-on-an-off-line-debian-system/

Answer (score 0):

you may have a look at the following link:
http://fcampanini.blogspot.co.uk/

In the post I wrote about how to manually configure wireless on a Linux box. @GAD3R you are right about lspci but I would run the command in this way:

```
lcpci | grep -A2 -i net
```

with the `-i` option within `grep`, it will not be case sensitive (reason why you probably have an empty result from `lspci`).

Post your output code.
Cheers
Francesco

PS:
as you don't have any output from `lspci` I would suggest you to check dmesg:

```
cat /var/log/dmesg | grep -i net
```

Comment: honestly, no output.

Comment: did you try the command I added in my edited answer ? Can you please specify which is the tablet model you are using and how did you succeed to install Debian on it ... which Debian version are you using ? Is this a distribution derived from Debian or an "original one" ?

Comment: I have add the information. However, still no output of your second command. x doesn't start at system starts, system starts directly enter to tty1, after executing `startx` the output is outlined at this post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307203/my-debian-installation-has-no-desktop-enviroment-and-no-internet-access?noredirect=1#comment540017_307203

Comment: Can you just use `lcpci` with no parameter and post the output and look within dmesg for any lines which may contain the strings _wireless_ or Realtek_

Comment: The device name is Realtek RTL8723BS WiFi/Bluetooth but it not shown in lspci. see my edit.

Comment: Have a look at this post, it is from a guy who had your same issue on an Ubuntu over a tablet: [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249936) You need to adapt it a little but it shows which packages you need ...