# is there a try debian without install option?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I made a usb installer, but I can't see this option as in ubuntu. Below is the screenshot. Is there a simple way that I can try debian out without destory my current system?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a live cd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using the [Debian live install](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/) images. They can boot to a live desktop, and also support installing from the live system (but you don't have to install them).

Comment: Does Multi-arch has live-cd?

Comment: `amd64` and `i386`

Comment: @buzhidao no, you specifically need to download one of the live images from the link in my answer; the multi-arch CD isn't a live CD.

Comment: Thanks, I will download a live cd and get some packages...

Comment: @GAD3R does multi-arch DVD ported with desktop environment?(lxde,lightdm etc...)

Comment: @buzhidao again, no, you need to pick either `amd64` or `i386` and one of the available desktop environments (Cinnamon, GNOME, KDE, LXDE, MATE, XFCE). The multi-arch images (CD or DVD) don't contain a live environment.

Comment: I mean after I have installed the multi-arch, do I have a desktop environment? do I have a desktop manager? I am not asking if it have a live environment before or during the installation.

Comment: @buzhidao ah right, like [your other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307203)? There should be a DE on the multi-arch DVD (GNOME probably).

Comment: Thanks, now I am clear. Maybe gnome is not suitable for my tablet. I may fix the wireless driver and try something else.

Comment: @StephenKitt Actually there is no DE on multi-arch, if you want one, you need the internet access.